# php characters in pdf turn to question marks when set to utf-8

Tags: php, html, pdf, encoding, utf-8

I'm using the "wordpress pdf templates" plugin.
In my php pdf generating code, I set the type to utf-8 with this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

When I do this, it turns the word workers' to:

> workers?

If I remove the utf-8 designation it looks like this:

> workersâ€™

My code is very simple and looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="post-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of an encoding mismatch.

One of the places to check is your wp-config.ph since that is one place that the encoding is also defined. Ref: https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-character-encoding-problem-in-wordpress-1480

Also note that you have a potential for problems to occur anywhere that one part of your system talks to another. Some of these components are:

- Your editor that you’re creating the PHP/HTML files in
- The web browser people are viewing your site through
- Your PHP web application running on the web server
- The MySQL database
- Anywhere else external you’re reading/writing data from (memcached, APIs, RSS feeds, etc)

Ref:
https://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php

Comment: you're encouraged to copy some of the relevant information from the links, so that the answer stays useful even if the links break.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I tried to add some of the main pieces here.  Sorry for not putting enough here the first time :)